# Show comments in Suggested Edits review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

It would be nice to see comments in the Suggested Edit review queue. It seems fairly frequent that people edit the question to add information that the OP provides only via comments, so being able to verify that without having to open the question in a new window would be nice.

Or maybe it's just me, not trusting those helpful editors...

Behold:

[image]